# Wrong values after resizing (resampling) rasters using cv2.resize (Python)

Tags: python, raster, image, resampling, borders

I have two images (aerial photographs):

- ImageA is 4740x4240 and cell size is 0.1 m
- ImageB is 1849x1653 and cell size is 0.25 m.

I want ImageB with the same size than ImageA. I used the following code to generate the new image:

```
import gdal
import cv2
from PIL import Image

## Input
imageA = cv2.imread(r"\\imageA.tif", -1)
imageB= cv2.imread(r"\\imageB.tif", -1)

## Output
output = r"\\imageC.tif"

## ImageA dimensions
x = imageA.shape[1]
y = imageA.shape[0]

## Resizing imageB
imageC = cv2.resize(src = imageB, dsize = (x, y), interpolation = cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
imageC = Image.fromarray(imageC).convert('L')
imageC.save(output)
```

As expected, the new image is 4740x4240 with a cell size of 0.1 m. But I get wrong values for left and right borders (value 255) as you can see below (for the right border). How could I resolve it and obtain interpolated values?

[image]